# How does AWS Glue crawler to exclude oracle schemas or oracle tables?

Tags: aws-glue

The customer plans to exclude oracle schemas or oracle tables using Glue crawler?

Glue crawler doesn't support /database/schema/tables for Oracle and MySQL database, I tried many different patterns to exclude oracle schemas or oracle tables, but the result isn't predicated.

How do I design the exclude patterns for Oracle database or MySQL database?

include-pattern: test/%

the test is the oracle service name.

I have added the following patterns to exclude schema APEX_030200 and WWV staring tables:

- APEX_030200.WWV*
- APEX_030200*
- test_apex_030200_wwv*
- test.APEX_030200.WWV_*
- test.APEX_030200.WWV*
- test.APEX_030200*
- test.APEX_030200*
- WWV*

But the result is the crawler includes schema APEX_030200's all tables.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Glue Crawler include and exclude patterns documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/define-crawler.html#crawler-data-stores-exclude), you can't specify a schema-name in your include path for database engines such as MySQL or Oracle, because they don't support a schema, at least in the sense of a namespace in a database.

- In most RDBMSs, like MS SQL Server, a schema represents a namespace.
- Oracle databases use the term differently, though. A schema is essentially the same thing as a user, as it represents objects owned by that user, independent of the database they're in.

So in the case of Oracle and MySQL, the exclude syntax is `database-name/table-name`, and not `database-name/schema-name/table-name`.

I don't know if there is a way to explicitly exlude what Oracle calls a schema.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.
How to exclude the users from Oracle or MySQL databases?

Comment: You can exclude databases and tables. As I stated in my answer above, I don’t know if there is a way to explicitly exclude what Oracle calls a schema, which effectively represents a user.

Comment: I tested once again. Actually, many alike tables was excluded, but there were several tables which was included into glue. It's wired.

Comment: Whether is exclude pattern case sensitive?
After many days tests, Exclude pattern result doesn't match with my expectation.
I plan to write a program to do this using API.

Comment: I added the exclude pattern: test/WWV*, test/OLAP*, but I still get the result: <br/>

- test.APEX_030200.WWV_FL starting tables, total 3.

- test.OLAPSYS.OLAP_** starting tables, total 2.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to exclude tables in Oracle, the pattern needs to have the following format

```
USER/EXCLUDE-PATTERN
```

Where `USER` is the table owner or the Oracle schema. `PATTERN` does honor the glob format [described in the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/define-crawler.html#crawler-data-stores-exclude). For example, I added

```
XXAPPS/P[!EORU]*
```

and in the crawler logs, got the confirmation that the table was excluded

[image]